# Why don't all photos appear in Months and Days views?

Tags: iphone, photos.app

In the Photos app, if I tap `Months` or `Days`, the oldest month it shows is September (I recently deleted everything from previous months or days) but if I tap `All Photos`, it shows a few random photos going back to June.

I'm sure some old photos are from June because of both their Date Taken meta-data and one is a picture of a paper document I signed and dated as June.

What are the Months and Days views really doing since they're not showing everything from those months and days?

Comment: Does the picture you think should appear actually have metadata saying it's from June, or are you just remembering it as being June?